# RabbitMQ: error_logger process high CPU usages

Tags: rabbitmq, cpu-usage

environment description:

kubernetes, ubuntu, 1 core, rabbitmq 3.7.24, erlang 22.3.1

rabbitmq about have 6 queues, each queue incoming/deliver 50/s. but CPU usage has 50%. log level is info.

top process:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gsGB8.png)

top -H -p pid

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YoZIB.png)

Why is there little log output but it takes up a lot of CPU.

Answer (score 1):

The major problem is Erlang's scheduler, not `error_logger`. There are two solutions to this problem.

1. Disable speculative busy waiting：

   ```
   RABBITMQ_SERVER_ADDITIONAL_ERL_ARGS="+sbwt none +sbwtdcpu none +sbwtdio none"
   ```
2. Reduce the number of schedulers：

   ```
   RABBITMQ_SERVER_ADDITIONAL_ERL_ARGS="+S 1:1"
   ```

This config should be written to the `/etc/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-env.conf` file. Please refer to [the RabitMQ Runtime Tuning documentation](https://www.rabbitmq.com/runtime.html#cpu).